# Error: "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection::select()"

Tags: codeigniter

I am struggling to solve this error and didn't understand it.

Model:

```
public function join()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    $id = $session->get('id');

    $db->select('subject_tbl.subject, mark_tbl.mark');
    $db->from('subject_tbl');
    $db->join('mark_tbl', 'mark_tbl.sub_id = subject_tbl.sub_id');
    $db->where('mark_tbl.id', $id);
    $query = $db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

It returns the error:

> Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection::select()

Controller:

```
public function s_mark()
{
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    if($session->has('id'))
    {
        $data['val'] = $this->obj->join();

        return view('mark_s', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of the error message say? It's important

Comment: only this error message is showing. error showing in this portion -" $db->select('subject_tbl.subject,mark_tbl.mark');"

Comment: @Janulakshmi follow the Codeigniter documentation https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html to connect your project with DB properly

Comment: There has to be more. There should be "...on ... on line ..."

Comment: There is no error when I using other operations. this error is only  occurring at  join operation

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller file, do some changes:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->joinModel = model('ModelNameHere');
}

public function s_mark()
{
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    if($session->has('id'))
    {
        $data['val'] = $this->joinModel->join();

        return view('mark_s', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two years late, got the same issue and had to dig up the answer.So anyway:

You've made a mistake in the model. The Query Builder is only loaded through the first use of table() method. Until then it is not loaded into the memory ([From their official doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#loading-the-query-builder))

So change the Model code to

```
public function join()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $session = \Config\Services::session();
    $id = $session->get('id');
    $builder = $db->table('subject_tbl');


    $builder->select('subject_tbl.subject, mark_tbl.mark');
    $builder->join('mark_tbl', 'mark_tbl.sub_id = subject_tbl.sub_id');
    $builder->where('mark_tbl.id', $id);
    $query = $builder->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I reviewed your source code. Have you configured the database settings in the .env file?

Comment: yes...there is no error when using select, insert and delete...is this join query is correct?

Comment: see my another answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).